# Is StartExecution api for AWS Step Function asynchronous?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have a use case where I want to start a step function asynchronously from one of my existing lambda function. For this, I am using the StartExecution API. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartExecution.html)

so does this API starts the step function asynchronously. if so, can someone please point me to the right documentation, where this is mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `StartExecution` method only verifies an execution can be started and triggers the execution (if needed), returning the executionArn.

The execution itself is asynchronous and you can get information about the status and output by calling [ListExecutions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_ListExecutions.html) and [DescribeExecution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_DescribeExecution.html).

So even if `StarExecution` is a synchronous call, the execution itself is asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks @javier. Though my understanding is also the same, but I did not find this thing mentioned anywhere in the aws doc. Or does this mean, step function by default is asynchronous irrespective the way it is triggered e.g StartExecution API, s3 event or cloundwatch events?

Comment: Step Functions executions are asynchronous. If you want to know when the step function has finished you need either to keep track of the execution or use some mechanism (like message queues) to communicate the status of the execution, so you can get notified once it is done